# Python 3 wxPython Toolbook TBK_BUTTONBAR crashes on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, wxpython

I start learning wxPython and I have a problem with the Toolbook's style=wx.TBK_BUTTONBAR.

I am running this little program under macOS Sierra (10.12.6), Python 3.6.2 and wxPython 4.0.0b1 :

```
import wx

def main():

    app = wx.App(True)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='test', size=(800, 600))

    toolbook = wx.Toolbook(frame, style=wx.TBK_BUTTONBAR)

    il = wx.ImageList(24, 24)
    il.Add(wx.Bitmap('ok.png')) # in the same folder as this script
    toolbook.SetImageList(il)

    toolbook.AddPage(wx.Panel(toolbook), 'test', imageId=0)

    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Everything works fine without defining a style but with the wx.TBK_BUTTONBAR active, it crashes with this message :

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)

Does anyone have the solution? I am searching since last week on many forums or groups… Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the size of ok.png correct? The ImageList is expecting (24,24).

Comment: Yes, all my png icon files have this size for my project. I also have a Toolbar with the same image file and it works perfectly.